# Get/describe istio egress rule

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I created few egress rules in my cluster and would like to verify that they were applied properly.

Is there a way to get/describe all created istio egress rules to manage the access policies ?

Comment: Found the command, it's: istioctl get egressrule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `istioctl` command for that: `istioctl get egressrules -o yaml`.

You can also get route rules and other Istio artifacts created by `istioctl`.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I have updated the post, thank you for reviewing it and for explaining the policy.